# Content Document download URL params

Tags: files, parameters, contentversion, contentdocument

I spend hours to find a way to control download behavior of pdf-files (when to download and when to show inline) and did not find anything.

What I got so far:

the main thing that do all files magic is

> /sfc/servlet.shepherd/ ....

1. We can download file by:

   - ContentVersion Id - `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<VERSION>`
   - ContentDocument Id - `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/<DOCUMENT>`
   - Zip archive by Ids separated by slash - `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<VERSION 1>/<VERSION 2>?`
2. For some reason in salesforce download links we can find the following parameter `operationContext=S1` OR `operationContext=CHATER`, which seems do nothing
3. Also **servlet.shepherd** can show preview image of pdf `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=SVGZ&versionId=<VERSION>`, where `?rendition=`  can be:

   - *SVGZ*
   - *THUMB120BY90*
   - *THUMB240BY180*
   - *THUMB720BY480*

All these options are not covered by official documentation and I feel there could be much more features. Does anybody know other options? Is there any documentation explaining all possible options?

UPD:
Added option with multiple files download as a zip provided by @cropredy

Comment: I would love to know if we can force inline behavior vs download, for pdfs I want it to open in browser window but it seems to just download the document and then the user has to click the download to open it.

Comment: @ScottMorrison, I don't think you can change that behavior programatically, but if you have a Visualforce page rendered as a PDF you can set 'content-disposition' header on the Visualforce page to determine what the browser does with it and there are also settings under "Setup" > "Security" > "File Upload and Download Security" to change how certain file extensions are handled by default within Salesforce (ex. ".pdf => download" or ".mp4 => execute in browser")

Comment: Though the hardcoded URL method works, it isn't officially supported. So i would request you upvote this idea [https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000PiVqQAK](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000PiVqQAK) and share it as well. Direct access to the images will be really helpful for use in custom applications and components.

Comment: Please beware that servlet.shepherd has problems with special characters: In case the file name contains special characters (e.g. äüö) a files name is changed to the Id of the ContentDocument/ContentVersion .

Answer (score 17):

Looks like there are some changes recently. I am seeing below pattern with API version 48

For authenticated users

```
/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06955000001UrOPAA0
```

For communities

```
/sfsites/c/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06955000001UrOPAA0
```

ID in the URL being content document ID.

Comment: Thank you a ton.  I didn't realize the communities url was prefixed now.

Answer (score 15):

You can also download multiple files as a zip

```
{!URLFOR('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' & delimitedSelectedIdList &'?')}
```

example:

```
{!URLFOR('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/068yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?')}
```

more details on my [blog](http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/03/16/download-multiple-contentversion-files-as-zip/)

Answer (score 1):

I came here because i have problem with displaying images on community site in incognito mode ( on the external user).
Normally i can display when I'm login by my salesforce user using this src img:

/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06955000001UrOPAA0

I showed up here that for communities i should try with this :

/sfsites/c/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06955000001UrOPAA0

But it still did not work.
What can be problem? What should I check more over ?

Comment: SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question or one of its other answers for reference, if relevant and helpful.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/187487)