# Display image in salesforce lightning component

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, aura, images

I have a contentversion file which I am using the following tag to view in my lightning component

```
<img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0690w0000000IPS"/>
```

However, it is downloading my file instead of displaying. Is there any way to just display instead of downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the url for download. Instead, you want to use renditionDownload.

It's explained in a few places I found:
http://blog.adityanaag.com/19/Thumbnails+in+VisualForce

[Content Document download URL params](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203030/content-document-download-url-params)